# Store pedestrian agents position in a txt

Tags: anylogic

I'm new on AnyLogic, I'm a universitary student, I'm working in my title project and I still can't get to save the coordinates of my agents in time. I've been working with this tool for near 3 months and just started to seek for help.

I tried with traceln(getX and getY), propperly written, but it only shows me the entrance position, how could I create a function to store this information onto a txt file? Or how could I create a new agent type to apply the steps above described

Please your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example to show you how to do this.

I have a custom pedestrian agent that gets created in the ped source block and a population, which starts of empty where all the pedestrians that gets created get added to.

[image]

This is just so that I can have the event to record the location inside the agent and the file object to write to is on main. So we need to access main from inside the agent.

In the file object, I just set it to write and selected a blank .txt file that I created.
You can read more about using the text file from the help - https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/text-file.html

[image]

Inside the pedestrian agent, I have an event that simply saves the location to the file in a new line.
I make use of the `"\t"` so that the txt file is tab-separated. You can use whatever separator you prefer.

[image]

You must remember to call the close command on the text file when you have finished writing to it. I simply called it on the destroy code of main. So it only "writes" the data to the text file when you close the model.

[image]

Here is the output from this very simple example

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to get close, but stil can't log the position of the pedestrian on the txt as you showed me, I do not know how to get the data, I'm using Windows 10 and it always give me some problems on the development projects at the university.

Comment: Could you help me with the details of the way to obtain the position, I've added 3 parameters to my agent type myPeople Id with getId value, x with getX and y with getY but it declares that this values can not be inserted to the field or something like that 
https://prnt.sc/1qdi96d

Comment: Hi @GerardoFernandezHormazabal my example was self-contained and has all the steps to get the location. Perhaps try and replicate my example in a new model and see if you can get it working, and then try and implement it in your model. 
For your other comment, this feels like a new question, please consider opening a new question. 
If you found my answer useful remember to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer friends, but the problem is that I can't get the Event function to work, how should I put it? That was why I asked my second question, thinking that of that way I could get the values

https://prnt.sc/1qgbjmn

Comment: I think that my problem is that I do not know how to add my own classes to desing my functions, egg for writing to file. I'll make a new topic

Comment: @GerardoFernandezHormazabalmy apologies, I see the screenshot showing the event and the code for writing the data to the text file was missing. See my updated answer. is this now sufficient for you? Perhaps you can delete the other question?

Comment: /Ben Vosloo thank you very much that was what i need, I'm leaving the link to my other question that it is related but doing the same with other way

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900794/anylogic-how-to-create-my-own-functions-to-write-pedestrian-positions-to-a-txt

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getX()` and `getY()` on agents does definitely give their current coordinates (assuming they are in a continuous space and not GIS/discrete space) so it's likely you're calling this on the wrong agents (e.g., calling it for your instance of Main instead of for some agents living in a population inside it).

Or you're not actually calling it at different simulation times (via, say, a cyclic event), so you're only getting the initial values.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I apologize for no answering before, could you help with a Step by Step on how to enable something like a cyclic event?

Do I need to create a new agent type?

I did the Hallway training and I just need to store the position every  1 or 5 seconds, into a .txt document.