# AnyLogic How to create my own classes and call them from pedestrian model?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am new with AnyLogic and I'm working on my title project at the university, but I don't get how to realize my own functions and how to call them from my model project.

I'm just making the Pedestrian tutorial, I have created the Hallway Station

I have created my own pedestrian population, called myPeople

I have created a cyclic event to try and record the positions on a TXT file called location.txt and after the help of a person of this community I did it (Question link: [Store pedestrian agents position in a txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731293/store-pedestrian-agents-position-in-a-txt/68853878?noredirect=1#comment121714346_68853878) )

The thing is that now I tried creating a class called MyPosition took from another question that I've found, but do not know how to make it work, how to call the methods. [Own class][1]

I want to take the data, work it, then store it. And all with cyclic events, so instead of using the default functions, I want to create my own fuctions.

I want to store the ID, X and Y coordinates of every agent every 5 seconds. Based on my other question BUT modifying the data before, e.g. rounding the positions to 3 decimals, or applying additions, or multiplications, or others operations.

Please your help

Answer (score 0):

when you build a class, the class is just that, to use it, you need to instantiate that class...

you can create for example a variable of type MyPosition and to instantiate it you will do:

```
variable=new MyPosition(id,x,y);
```

and the you can call your methods inside your class using variable.getX() for example, if you created such a method.

if you want to add many points, then you can create a collection with element type MyPosition, and store all those variables there to have a list that is populated with a new element every 5 seconds:

```
collectionName.add(new MyPosition(id,x,y));
```